# Как без изменений сохранить в JSON и потом считать Float32Array

Tags: javascript, json

Я использую js библиотеку(face-api.js) для распознавания лиц, которая возвращает некий массив из имени человека и соотвествующих ему дескрипторов. Проблема в том, что библиотека реализована таким образом, что б обучаться на лету и возвращать результат на промисах - т.е если использовать огромные датасеты, то загрузка будет вечной. Моя цель один раз обучить и сохранить куда-то массив всех дескрипторов.
Теперь к проблеме. Библиотека возвращает такой массив:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после этого я сохранял его в JSON, но после JSON.parse я получал другой масив - технически такой же, но без `t` перед каждым объектом + пропадают поля `label` и `descriptors`, которые видно только если раскрыть объект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот два вопроса:

1. как сохранить в формате JSON исходный массив без изменений как на скринах
2. что это за "t" перед каждым обьектом.

Спасибо за ответ.

PS(скорее всего я чего-то не знаю и просто туплю)

Comment: Напишите код сохранения. Скорее всего вы сохраняете не тот объект

Comment: `const labeledFaceDescriptors = await loadLabeledImages();  
    var json_str = '{"parent":' + JSON.stringify(labeledFaceDescriptors) + "}";  
    localStorage.setItem("data", json_str);`

Comment: Скорее всего библиотека возвращает объекты класса, у которых есть методе и геттеры\сеттеры. Соответственно, после `JSON.parse()` вам надо снова создать объекты класса. Для более точного ответа  сделайте воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko, спасибо, сработало